# Element made inert or hidden event

Tags: javascript, html, performance, dom-events

Is it possible to detect when elements are hidden such as from inert or hidden?

I have a sitemap page and my links use an `IntersectionObserver` and the `mouseover` event to detect when links are very visible to preload data. Especially on a page with a lot of links like a sitemap page this can get quite expensive or at least a little annoying and noisy on the profiler.

One of the ideas I would like to try would be to disable the observer and prefetching logic when links are hidden inside a disclosure widget a little like the `details` element or in my case an accordion.

I can explicitly feed the data in (in my case probably with a React provider) or just not use that functionality on this pages links. But I thought it might be elegant to detect if there was a way to detect if the element is hidden or made inert inside a the disclosure widget.

So basically one option I want to explore would be:

- Detect if an anchor element is underneath an `inert`, `hidden`, or `opacity: 0` element.
- Detect if an anchor element becomes untabbable.

Comment: Elements with `opacity: 0` can be interacted with. They are only visually hidden, but their box (and thus interactive area) is still present.

Answer (score 2):

You can use somthing like this to get all the elements which are hidded. I have used getComputedStyle function to get the final CSS applied to the elements. :

```
const anchorElement = document.querySelector('a');
const computedStyle = window.getComputedStyle(anchorElement);

// Check if hidden
if (computedStyle.display === 'none' || computedStyle.visibility === 'hidden' || computedStyle.opacity === '0') {
  
}
```

If you want to check if the anchor element is keyboard-focusable or not, you can use something like this :
const anchorElement = document.querySelector('a');

```
// Check if untabbable
if (anchorElement.tabIndex === -1) {

}
```

Comment: Note that a child of a hidden element is also hidden, which is not apparent via the declared styles of (i.e. the result of `getComputedStyle()` for) the child.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of any native way to detect what you're looking for, but you should be able to build it yourself. Here are some pointers:

- Use the [`Element.closest()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest) to query whether an element (or an ancestor) has the `inert` or `hidden` attribute.
- Use the [`Element.getAttribute()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getAttribute) to check if an element is untabbable (i.e. has its [`tabindex` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/tabindex) with a negative value).
- Use the [`Element.getBoundingClientRect()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect) or [`Element.getClientRects()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getClientRects) to find out whether an element is visually hidden.
- Use the [`getComputedStyle(element)` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle) to find out whether an element is declared to be hidden.
- Use a [`MutationObserver`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) to detect attribute and DOM-tree changes.

---

Personally, I recommend to instead use an explicit way of stating whether a link should preload, e.g. the presence/absence of a certain attribute.

Such an attribute would allow for more flexibility: The `IntersectionObserver` would not have to itself compute whether a link should preload (repeatedly), and the attribute may be set initially (e.g. in the HTML source) or deferred (e.g. when entering the viewport before preloading).